# Nodejs: MongoDB on Docker-Compose throwing "getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongo1" error on Macbook

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I've gone through most of the questions on this error, but they haven't worked for me, hence asking here.
Nodejs Application is running on a Macbook M1, running local MongoDB instance created in docker-desktop using docker-compose. Docker desktop is running. When I run `docker-compose up` I can see docker logging various mongo1_1 messages:

```
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:02.761+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"-","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:02.763+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:02.763+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:02.764+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:02.764+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:02.764+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:02.764+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:02.764+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"main","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:02.765+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":1,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"065fa0971db9"}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:02.765+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"5.0.9","gitVersion":"6f7dae919422dcd7f4892c10ff20cdc721ad00e6","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"ubuntu2004","distarch":"aarch64","target_arch":"aarch64"}}}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:02.765+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Ubuntu","version":"20.04"}}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:02.765+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"net":{"bindIp":"*","port":27017},"replication":{"replSet":"test-replica-set"}}}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:02.766+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22271,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Detected unclean shutdown - Lock file is not empty","attr":{"lockFile":"/data/db/mongod.lock"}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:02.766+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22270,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Storage engine to use detected by data files","attr":{"dbpath":"/data/db","storageEngine":"wiredTiger"}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:02.766+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22302,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Recovering data from the last clean checkpoint."}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:02.766+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22297,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine. See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:02.766+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22315,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Opening WiredTiger","attr":{"config":"create,cache_size=3413M,session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),builtin_extension_config=(zstd=(compression_level=6)),file_manager=(close_idle_time=600,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress,compact_progress],"}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.421+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1656315543:421788][1:0xffff96938980], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 9 through 10"}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.441+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1656315543:441288][1:0xffff96938980], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 10 through 10"}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.482+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1656315543:482196][1:0xffff96938980], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_ALL] Main recovery loop: starting at 9/65792 to 10/256"}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.482+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1656315543:482601][1:0xffff96938980], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 9 through 10"}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.512+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1656315543:512341][1:0xffff96938980], file:collection-2--2446768745455631252.wt, txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 10 through 10"}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.531+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1656315543:531400][1:0xffff96938980], file:collection-2--2446768745455631252.wt, txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_ALL] Set global recovery timestamp: (1656314127, 1)"}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.531+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1656315543:531471][1:0xffff96938980], file:collection-2--2446768745455631252.wt, txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_ALL] Set global oldest timestamp: (1656313827, 1)"}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.535+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1656315543:535280][1:0xffff96938980], WT_SESSION.checkpoint: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 12, snapshot max: 12 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (1656313827, 1) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (1656314127, 1) base write gen: 234"}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.540+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger opened","attr":{"durationMillis":774}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.540+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"RECOVERY", "id":23987,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp","attr":{"recoveryTimestamp":{"$timestamp":{"t":1656314127,"i":1}}}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.540+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"RECOVERY", "id":5380106, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger oldestTimestamp","attr":{"oldestTimestamp":{"$timestamp":{"t":1656313827,"i":1}}}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.540+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4366408, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"No table logging settings modifications are required for existing WiredTiger tables","attr":{"loggingEnabled":false}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.541+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22383,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"The size storer reports that the oplog contains","attr":{"numRecords":525,"dataSize":53787}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.541+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22384,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Scanning the oplog to determine where to place markers for truncation"}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.541+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22382,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger record store oplog processing finished","attr":{"durationMillis":0}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.542+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22262,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Timestamp monitor starting"}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.544+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22120,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Access control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.546+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915702, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Updated wire specification","attr":{"oldSpec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true},"newSpec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":13,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":13,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.546+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":5071100, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Clearing temp directory"}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.548+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20536,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Flow Control is enabled on this deployment"}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.548+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":5380103, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Unpin oldest timestamp request","attr":{"service":"_wt_startup","requestedTs":{"$timestamp":{"t":1656313827,"i":1}}}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.549+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":20997,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Refreshed RWC defaults","attr":{"newDefaults":{}}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.549+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":20625,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture","attr":{"dataDirectory":"/data/db/diagnostic.data"}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.551+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":6015317, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Setting new configuration state","attr":{"newState":"ConfigStartingUp","oldState":"ConfigPreStart"}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.552+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"ReadConcernMajorityNotAvailableYet: Read concern majority reads are currently not possible.","nextWakeupMillis":200}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.552+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4280500, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Attempting to create internal replication collections"}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.553+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4280501, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Attempting to load local voted for document"}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.553+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4280502, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Searching for local Rollback ID document"}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.554+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21529,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Initializing rollback ID","attr":{"rbid":4}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.554+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":501401,  "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Incrementing the rollback ID after unclean shutdown"}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.555+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21532,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Incremented the rollback ID","attr":{"rbid":5}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.555+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4280504, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Cleaning up any partially applied oplog batches & reading last op from oplog"}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.556+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21557,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Removing unapplied oplog entries after oplogTruncateAfterPoint","attr":{"oplogTruncateAfterPoint":{"":{"$timestamp":{"t":1656314147,"i":1}}}}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.556+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21553,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Truncating oplog from truncateAfterOplogEntryTimestamp (non-inclusive)","attr":{"truncateAfterOplogEntryTimestamp":{"$timestamp":{"t":1656314147,"i":1}},"oplogTruncateAfterPoint":{"$timestamp":{"t":1656314147,"i":1}}}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.556+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21554,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Replication recovery oplog truncation finished","attr":{"durationMillis":0}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.557+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21544,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Recovering from stable timestamp","attr":{"stableTimestamp":{"$timestamp":{"t":1656314127,"i":1}},"topOfOplog":{"ts":{"$timestamp":{"t":1656314147,"i":1}},"t":7},"appliedThrough":{"ts":{"$timestamp":{"t":0,"i":0}},"t":-1}}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.557+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21545,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Starting recovery oplog application at the stable timestamp","attr":{"stableTimestamp":{"$timestamp":{"t":1656314127,"i":1}}}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.557+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5466604, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Start point for recovery oplog application exists in oplog. No adjustment necessary","attr":{"startPoint":{"$timestamp":{"t":1656314127,"i":1}}}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.557+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21550,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Replaying stored operations from startPoint (exclusive) to endPoint (inclusive)","attr":{"startPoint":{"$timestamp":{"t":1656314127,"i":1}},"endPoint":{"$timestamp":{"t":1656314147,"i":1}}}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.557+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21536,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Completed oplog application for recovery","attr":{"numOpsApplied":2,"numBatches":1,"applyThroughOpTime":{"ts":{"$timestamp":{"t":1656314147,"i":1}},"t":7}}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.557+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4280505, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Creating any necessary TenantMigrationAccessBlockers for unfinished migrations"}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.558+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4280506, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Reconstructing prepared transactions"}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.559+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4280507, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Loaded replica set config, scheduled callback to set local config"}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.559+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4280508, "ctx":"ReplCoord-0","msg":"Attempting to set local replica set config; validating config for startup"}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.560+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20714,   "ctx":"LogicalSessionCacheRefresh","msg":"Failed to refresh session cache, will try again at the next refresh interval","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Replication has not yet been configured"}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.560+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20711,   "ctx":"LogicalSessionCacheReap","msg":"Failed to reap transaction table","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Replication has not yet been configured"}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.560+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":40440,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Starting the TopologyVersionObserver"}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.561+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":40445,   "ctx":"TopologyVersionObserver","msg":"Started TopologyVersionObserver"}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.561+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4280509, "ctx":"ReplCoord-0","msg":"Local configuration validated for startup"}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.561+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":6015317, "ctx":"ReplCoord-0","msg":"Setting new configuration state","attr":{"newState":"ConfigSteady","oldState":"ConfigStartingUp"}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.561+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21392,   "ctx":"ReplCoord-0","msg":"New replica set config in use","attr":{"config":{"_id":"test-replica-set","version":1,"term":7,"members":[{"_id":0,"host":"mongo1:27017","arbiterOnly":false,"buildIndexes":true,"hidden":false,"priority":1,"tags":{},"secondaryDelaySecs":0,"votes":1}],"protocolVersion":1,"writeConcernMajorityJournalDefault":true,"settings":{"chainingAllowed":true,"heartbeatIntervalMillis":2000,"heartbeatTimeoutSecs":10,"electionTimeoutMillis":10000,"catchUpTimeoutMillis":-1,"catchUpTakeoverDelayMillis":30000,"getLastErrorModes":{},"getLastErrorDefaults":{"w":1,"wtimeout":0},"replicaSetId":{"$oid":"62b94c9af73b84ac24f02cc5"}}}}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.561+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21393,   "ctx":"ReplCoord-0","msg":"Found self in config","attr":{"hostAndPort":"mongo1:27017"}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.561+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21358,   "ctx":"ReplCoord-0","msg":"Replica set state transition","attr":{"newState":"STARTUP2","oldState":"STARTUP"}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.561+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21320,   "ctx":"ReplCoord-0","msg":"Updated term","attr":{"term":7}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.561+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21306,   "ctx":"ReplCoord-0","msg":"Starting replication storage threads"}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.562+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4280512, "ctx":"ReplCoord-0","msg":"No initial sync required. Attempting to begin steady replication"}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.562+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21358,   "ctx":"ReplCoord-0","msg":"Replica set state transition","attr":{"newState":"RECOVERING","oldState":"STARTUP2"}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.562+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21299,   "ctx":"ReplCoord-0","msg":"Starting replication fetcher thread"}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.562+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21300,   "ctx":"ReplCoord-0","msg":"Starting replication applier thread"}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.562+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21301,   "ctx":"ReplCoord-0","msg":"Starting replication reporter thread"}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.562+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21224,   "ctx":"OplogApplier-0","msg":"Starting oplog application"}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.562+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4280511, "ctx":"ReplCoord-0","msg":"Set local replica set config"}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.563+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock"}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.563+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"0.0.0.0"}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.563+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23016,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Waiting for connections","attr":{"port":27017,"ssl":"off"}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.563+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21358,   "ctx":"OplogApplier-0","msg":"Replica set state transition","attr":{"newState":"SECONDARY","oldState":"RECOVERING"}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.563+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ELECTION", "id":4615652, "ctx":"OplogApplier-0","msg":"Starting an election, since we've seen no PRIMARY in election timeout period","attr":{"electionTimeoutPeriodMillis":10000}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.563+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ELECTION", "id":21438,   "ctx":"OplogApplier-0","msg":"Conducting a dry run election to see if we could be elected","attr":{"currentTerm":7}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.563+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ELECTION", "id":21444,   "ctx":"ReplCoord-0","msg":"Dry election run succeeded, running for election","attr":{"newTerm":8}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.563+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ELECTION", "id":6015300, "ctx":"ReplCoord-0","msg":"Storing last vote document in local storage for my election","attr":{"lastVote":{"term":8,"candidateIndex":0}}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.564+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ELECTION", "id":21450,   "ctx":"ReplCoord-0","msg":"Election succeeded, assuming primary role","attr":{"term":8}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.564+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21358,   "ctx":"ReplCoord-0","msg":"Replica set state transition","attr":{"newState":"PRIMARY","oldState":"SECONDARY"}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.564+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21106,   "ctx":"ReplCoord-0","msg":"Resetting sync source to empty","attr":{"previousSyncSource":":27017"}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.564+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21359,   "ctx":"ReplCoord-0","msg":"Entering primary catch-up mode"}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.564+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":6015304, "ctx":"ReplCoord-0","msg":"Skipping primary catchup since we are the only node in the replica set."}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.564+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21363,   "ctx":"ReplCoord-0","msg":"Exited primary catch-up mode"}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.564+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21107,   "ctx":"ReplCoord-0","msg":"Stopping replication producer"}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.564+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21239,   "ctx":"ReplBatcher","msg":"Oplog buffer has been drained","attr":{"term":8}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.565+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21239,   "ctx":"ReplBatcher","msg":"Oplog buffer has been drained","attr":{"term":8}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.565+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21343,   "ctx":"RstlKillOpThread","msg":"Starting to kill user operations"}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.565+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21344,   "ctx":"RstlKillOpThread","msg":"Stopped killing user operations"}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.565+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21340,   "ctx":"RstlKillOpThread","msg":"State transition ops metrics","attr":{"metrics":{"lastStateTransition":"stepUp","userOpsKilled":0,"userOpsRunning":0}}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.566+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4508103, "ctx":"OplogApplier-0","msg":"Increment the config term via reconfig"}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.566+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":6015313, "ctx":"OplogApplier-0","msg":"Replication config state is Steady, starting reconfig"}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.566+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":6015317, "ctx":"OplogApplier-0","msg":"Setting new configuration state","attr":{"newState":"ConfigReconfiguring","oldState":"ConfigSteady"}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.566+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21353,   "ctx":"OplogApplier-0","msg":"replSetReconfig config object parses ok","attr":{"numMembers":1}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.566+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":51814,   "ctx":"OplogApplier-0","msg":"Persisting new config to disk"}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.566+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":6015315, "ctx":"OplogApplier-0","msg":"Persisted new config to disk"}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.566+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":6015317, "ctx":"OplogApplier-0","msg":"Setting new configuration state","attr":{"newState":"ConfigSteady","oldState":"ConfigReconfiguring"}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.566+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21392,   "ctx":"OplogApplier-0","msg":"New replica set config in use","attr":{"config":{"_id":"test-replica-set","version":1,"term":8,"members":[{"_id":0,"host":"mongo1:27017","arbiterOnly":false,"buildIndexes":true,"hidden":false,"priority":1,"tags":{},"secondaryDelaySecs":0,"votes":1}],"protocolVersion":1,"writeConcernMajorityJournalDefault":true,"settings":{"chainingAllowed":true,"heartbeatIntervalMillis":2000,"heartbeatTimeoutSecs":10,"electionTimeoutMillis":10000,"catchUpTimeoutMillis":-1,"catchUpTakeoverDelayMillis":30000,"getLastErrorModes":{},"getLastErrorDefaults":{"w":1,"wtimeout":0},"replicaSetId":{"$oid":"62b94c9af73b84ac24f02cc5"}}}}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.566+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21393,   "ctx":"OplogApplier-0","msg":"Found self in config","attr":{"hostAndPort":"mongo1:27017"}}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.566+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":6015310, "ctx":"OplogApplier-0","msg":"Starting to transition to primary."}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.566+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":6015309, "ctx":"OplogApplier-0","msg":"Logging transition to primary to oplog on stepup"}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.567+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20657,   "ctx":"OplogApplier-0","msg":"IndexBuildsCoordinator::onStepUp - this node is stepping up to primary"}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.567+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21331,   "ctx":"OplogApplier-0","msg":"Transition to primary complete; database writes are now permitted"}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.567+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":6015306, "ctx":"OplogApplier-0","msg":"Applier already left draining state, exiting."}
mongo1_1             | {"t":{"$date":"2022-06-27T07:39:03.567+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"ReadConcernMajorityNotAvailableYet: Read concern majority reads are currently not possible.","nextWakeupMillis":400}}
```

Nodejs app using MongoDB image on `docker` is throwing error:

> MongoServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongo1
> at Timeout._onTimeout (/myapp/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:330:38)
> at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)

I can see mongo running using `docker ps`:

[image]

Here is my docker-compose-yml:

```
services:
  mongo1:
    image: mongo:latest
    command: ["--replSet", "test-replica-set", "--bind_ip_all", "--port", "27017"]
    volumes:
      - mongodbdata1:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    expose:
      - 27017
    networks:
      - retro
  redis:
    image: redis:6.0.0
    ports:
      - '${REDIS_PORT}:6379'
    networks:
      - retro

  dependencies:
    image: dadarek/wait-for-dependencies
    depends_on:
      - mongo1
      - redis
    networks:
      - retro
    command: mongo1:27017 redis:6379

  networks:
    retro:

  volumes:
    mongodbdata1:
      driver: local
```

I've tried setting up `container-name` and `hostname` to `mongo1` without any success.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you share the connection string you are using ?

Comment: URI is set as ```DATABASE_URI=mongodb://localhost:27017/```

Comment: Do you have the same error replacing localhost in connection string with 127.0.0.1 or mongo1 (container alias) ?

Comment: Yes, tried `DATABASE_URI=mongodb://mongo1:27017/` and `DATABASE_URI=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/` without success.

Comment: Ok so here is a couple things you can try : 
- Removing the replicaSetPart (which is usefull if you run multiple mongoDb containers for data replication and the replicas need specials params in connection string)
- Add mongo1 alias for 127.0.0.1 in your etc/hosts file 
- Specify a DB to your connection string for example: mongodb://localhost:27017/admin
- Use another tool like Compass to check if you can connect to your instance

Comment: I can't add anything to etc/hosts, it is locked for me. Removing the replica set crashes the application. adding a DB to the connection string generates the same error (db does exist). Using MongoDB Compass, I can't connect unless I check `Direct Connection` at which point `localhost:27017` connects to DB.

Comment: Well so try to set the connection URL to : mongodb://localhost:27017/?directConnection=true

Comment: @Guillaume how can I add a database name to this connection string that you suggested `mongodb://localhost:27017/?directConnection=true`

Comment: mongodb://localhost:27017/admin?directConnection=true. Here is some documentation about Mongo connection URLs : https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/